# Swift | Не получается добавить элементы в UIScrollView

Tags: swift, autolayout, uiscrollview

UIScrollView исчезает при добавлении элементов в него, без элементов все вроде работает как надо.
В коде для примера пытаю добавить yellowView в scrollView, если закомментировать его добавление и констрейты, то все работает. В чем может быть проблема, куда копать? Уже кучу ресурсов пересмотрел, ответ не смог найти.

UIViewController:

```
private lazy var contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height + 400)

private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.frame = view.bounds
    scrollView.contentSize = contentSize
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
    return scrollView
}()

private lazy var contentView: UIView = {
    let contentView = UIView()
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.frame.size = contentSize
    contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    return contentView
}()

private let yellowView: UIView = {
    let yellowView = UIView()
    yellowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    yellowView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    return yellowView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    makeUI()
}

private func makeUI() {
    view.backgroundColor = BaseColors.backgroundColor
    
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.addSubview(yellowView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        yellowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        yellowView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
        yellowView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -20),
        yellowView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400)
    )]
}
```

Прикрепляю скриншоты как выглядит результат с и без yellowView.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы задали

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

и

```
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Но констрейнты для них не установили. Попробуйте закомментировать эти строчки и увидите, что все заработало.

Comment: Да, все заработало! 
Надо мне по лучше разобраться с translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints.
Спасибо большое!)

Comment: Пожалуйста, you are welcome)